# Parsing a file and replacing White spaces fond within double quotes using Java

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I am reading a file and trying to modify it in the following order:

1. if line is empty `trim()`
2. if line ends with `\` strip that char and add next line to it.
3. The complete line contains double quotes and there are white spaces between the quotes, replace the white space with `~`. 
      For example: `"This is text within double quotes"`
      change to  :  `"This~is~text~within~double~quotes"`

This code is working but buggy. 
Here is the issue when it finds a line that ends with \ and others that done.

```
for example: 
line 1 and \
line 2
line 3
```

so Instead of having

```
line 1 and line 2
line 3
```

I have this:

```
line 1 and line 2     line 3
```

Coded updated:

```
public List<String> OpenFile() throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            //StringBuilder concatenatedLine = new StringBuilder();
            List<String> formattedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            //Pattern matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            boolean addToPreviousLine;
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                line.trim();

            }

            if (line.contains("\"")) {
                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(line);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    String match = matcher.group();
                    line = line.replace(match, match.replaceAll("\\s+", "~"));
                }

            }

            if (line.endsWith("\\")) {
                addToPreviousLine = false;
                line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
                formattedStrings.add(line);
            } else {
                addToPreviousLine = true;

            }

            if (addToPreviousLine) {
                int previousLineIndex = formattedStrings.size() - 1;
                if (previousLineIndex > -1) {
                    // Combine the previous line and current line
                    String previousLine = formattedStrings.remove(previousLineIndex);
                    line = previousLine + " " + line;
                    formattedStrings.add(line);
                }
            }
            testScan(formattedStrings);
            //concatenatedLine.setLength(0);
        }
        return formattedStrings;
    }
```

Comment: This make no sense, if the line is empty why do you need a `trim()`?

Comment: `if line is empty trim()` does not make sense.

Comment: Try debugging your code. In any case, `matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));` removes whitespace - it does not add the tilde.

Comment: @RC. the indentation is off.

Comment: @Glorfindel I see it now.. thanks

Comment: @rc I think the op wants to get rid of unnecessary empty space by using trim()?

Comment: it's either empty or contains spaces but not both (AFAIK, or maybe Schrodinger `String`s are a thing :p)

Comment: Correct, I am using trim() to get ready of blank lines as it was giving me errors if my line is blank. Any other recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I'm giving you what you need, without trying to write all the code for you.  You just need to figure out where to place these snippets.

If line is empty trim()

```
if (line.matches("\\s+")) {
    line = "";
    // I don't think you want to add an empty line to your return result.  If you do, just omit the continue;
    continue;
}
```

If line contains double quotes and white spaces in them, replace the white space with ~. For example: `"This is text within double quotes"` change to : `"This~is~text~within~double~quotes"`

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    line = line.replace(match, match.replaceAll("\\s+", "~"));
}
```

If line ends with `\` strip that char and add the next line.  You need to have flag to track when to do this.

```
if (line.endsWith("\\")) {
    addToPreviousLine = true;
    line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
} else {
    addToPreviousLine = false;
}
```

Now, to add the next line to the previous line you'll need something like (Figure out where to place this snippet):

```
if (addToPreviousLine) {
    int previousLineIndex = formattedStrings.size() - 1;
    if (previousLineIndex > -1) {
        // Combine the previous line and current line
        String previousLine = formattedStrings.remove(previousLineIndex);
        line = previousLine + " " + line;
    }
}
```

You still do not need the `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.  Just modify the current line and add the current line to your `formattedStrings` `List`.

Comment: modified the question, please take a look

Comment: @Moe Updated answer with what you need, but you have to figure out how to place all the pieces together correctly.

Comment: @Moe Everything you need is in the answer I provided. Debug the code you've written, experiment where the snippets should go and you'll get the answer. I will say that the Boolean flag addToPreviousLine should be declared before you start reading the file.

Comment: you are correct, it just needed some tweaks. I like how you did your if(true) do... this showed me a new possibilities  thanks again for you help on this??

Comment: @Moe You're welcome and glad you were able to figure it all out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with regex, so here's a programmatic method to do it:

```
    String string = "He said, \"Hello Mr Nice Guy\"";

    // split it along the quotes
    String splitString[] = string.split("\"");

    // loop through, each odd indexted item is inside quotations
    for(int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 > 0) {
            splitString[i] = splitString[i].replaceAll(" ", "~");
        }
    }

    String finalString = "";

    // re-build the string w/ quotes added back in
    for(int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 > 0) {
            finalString += "\"" + splitString[i] + "\"";
        } else {
            finalString += splitString[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(finalString);
```

Output: He said, "Hello~Mr~Nice~Guy"

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (line.contains("\"")) {
                   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                   Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(line);
                   while (matcher.find()) {
                   matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                }
```

I would do this

```
if (line.matches(("\"([^\"]+)\"")) {
               line=   line.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                }
```

**How can I add this to what I have above ?**

```
concatenatedLine.append(line); 
String fullLine = concatenatedLine.toString();  
if (fullLine.contains("\"")) {
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(fullLine);
 while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
 formattedStrings.add(sb.toString());
 }else
   formattedStrings.add(fullLine);
```

Comment: I agree, I tried that but it didn't work. something is wrong. I modified the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Step 3:

```
String text;
text = text.replaceAll("\\s", "~");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace spaces occur within double quotes with `~`s,

```
if (line.contains("\"")) {
    String line = "\"This is a line with spaces\"";
    String result = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
          result = m.group(1).replace(" ", "~");
    }
}
```

Comment: modified the question, please take a look